# "AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

Use Case :
I have two application :

1) First one is a Spring boot application, we are exposing our rest endpoint from here.

I want to secure my first application using Azure AD when called from second application and I want to do it in a silent way, that is I should not be prompted for username and password when service to service call happens.

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AADAuthenticationFilter aadAuthFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();

        http.addFilterBefore(aadAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}

@RestController
public class MyRestController{
  @RequestMapping(value = "/api/todolist", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addNewTodoItem(@RequestBody TodoItem item) {
        item.setID(todoList.size() + 1);
        todoList.add(todoList.size(), item);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Entity created", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

2) Second application is calling this Rest service. (Can you consider this as a java client which is just calling our rest service and then doing some processing).

I want to secure my first application using Azure AD when called from second application and I want to do it in a silent way that is we should not be prompted for username and password when service to service call happens

below is the code :

```
package sample.aad.security;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import ch.qos.logback.core.net.SyslogOutputStream;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token");
        Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        params.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        params.put("client_id", "b2846a59-33e9-4046-8c94-795d8087f453");
        params.put("client_secret", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        params.put("resource", APPID);

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0)
                postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");// multipart/form-data
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        String output;
        String last = null;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
            if (last == null) {
                last = output;
            } else {
                last.concat(output);
            }
        }

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(last.toString());

        System.out.println(jsonObj.get("access_token"));
        System.out.println(jsonObj.get("token_type"));

        invokeRestUrlClientStatic(jsonObj.get("token_type") + " " + jsonObj.get("access_token"));

    }


    public static void invokeRestUrlClientStatic(String accessToken) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Invoking");
            System.out.println(accessToken);
            // Call to Rest service from First Application
            URL url = new URL(" http://localhost:8080/api/todolist/");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", accessToken);

            String input = "{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}";

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Note : I dont have any WebUi in either of the application from where user can login.

But I am getting below error :

**Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: {"error_description":"AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in.\r\nTrace ID: b27a4ce6-f1ed-4a5c-b28f-6ee16f990400\r\nCorrelation ID: 168e6a13-8cf6-409f-864a-9f190746edfd\r\nTimestamp: 2018-03-17 10:46:35Z","error":"invalid_grant"}**
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:107) ~[adal4j-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:816) ~[adal4j-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$100(AuthenticationContext.java:64) ~[adal4j-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]

Am I missing something so that it works.

I have also tried below code (for my second Application): But still getting same error

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, Exception {

```
String app_id_uri = "APP ID URL";
String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";
String clientId = "b2846a59-33e9-4046-8c94-795d8087f453";
String clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
AuthenticationContext context = null;
AuthenticationResult result = null;
ExecutorService service = null;
ClientCredential credential= null;
try {
    service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true, service);
    credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(app_id_uri, credential,null);
    result = future.get();
} finally {
    service.shutdown();
}
String accessToken = null;
if (result == null) {
    throw new ServiceUnavailableException("authentication result was null");
} else {
    accessToken = result.getAccessToken();
    System.out.println("Access Token: " + accessToken);
}


// Call to my rest service using above accessToken
```

}

Comment: It seems like that authentication filter is trying to get an access token for Graph API as the calling user. You probably need a JWT Bearer authentication filter.

Comment: @juunas can you please elaborate more on this or if you can give me an example that would be of great help to me

Comment: I haven't done this one personally, but this page seems good: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt. In the case of Azure AD, you do not need to (and should not) hard-code the signing keys. You would need to configure the JWT handler to get the metadata from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/.well-known/openid-configuration`. Then you also need to make sure the allowed *audience* matches your `APPID` in the client.